# Discarding message for event 0 because of too many unprocessed messages

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I added two text fileds to my project , I connect on of them to its related property the project works fine , once i connect the second and run then start editing the second text field the application stop responding and after some time it gives me the following error in the log

```
Discarding message for event 0 because of too many unprocessed messages
```

i tried to delete is and connect it again many times it has the same problem

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7857323/ios5-what-does-discarding-message-for-event-0-because-of-too-many-unprocessed-m

Comment: but this answer is not present my case

Answer (score -7, accepted):

The problem solved when I use the following text field delegate

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField{
    return NO;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Just my 2$. That nothing to do with the delegate you mentioned. I ran into this issue while using MapKit, couldn't figured out what was the issue but restarting my iPhone fixed it!!!

[EDIT]
Got the reason why this happens. If location manager is running other than the main thread context then this happens intermittently. I was using location manager with NSTimer.