# Xcode leak tool stuck on MapkKit/CllocationManager Ios8

Tags: ios, xcode, memory-leaks

I have strange problem while using Xcode tools trying to find leaks in my App.
All my screens are working ok with the tool except the screen with mapView (e.g I have some registration screens and then the user proceed to MapView screen , in case the user logged in the Mapview screen opens). I think that the problem is somehow concerned to CllocationmManager
but I am not sure because the app simply stuck while using the leaking tool.
I receive the following Log from my Device :

```
timed[53] <Notice>: (Note ) CoreTime: Received time 10/21/2014 15:54:04±0.00 from "GPS" 
timed[53] <Notice>: (Note ) CoreTime: Want active time in 3332.92min. Need active time in 
8332.92min. Remaining retry interval: 0.000000min.
<Notice>: (Note ) CoreTime: Received time 10/21/2014 15:54:09±0.00 from "GPS"
<Notice>: (Note ) CoreTime: Want active time in 3332.82min. Need active time in 8332.82min.        
CommCenter[69] <Error>: throttleCallBack(): Clearing throttle timer on context ID 0
CommCenter[69] <Error>: throttleCallBack(): Clearing throttle timer on context ID 1
CommCenter[69] <Error>: throttleCallBack(): Clearing throttle timer on context ID 2
<Error>: throttleCallBack(): Clearing throttle timer on context ID 3
timed[53] <Notice>: (Note ) CoreTime: Received time 10/21/2014 15:54:14±0.00 from "GPS"
 timed[53] <Notice>: (Note ) CoreTime: Want active time in 3332.75min. Need active time in     
 CommCenter[69] <Error>: throttleCallBack(): Clearing throttle timer on context ID 0
 CommCenter[69] <Error>: throttleCallBack(): Clearing throttle timer on context ID 1

CoreLocation: Discarding message for event 0 because of too many unprocessed messages
```

I think the last line is the most important according to that link: [iOS5 What does “Discarding message for event 0 because of too many unprocessed messages” mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7857323/ios5-what-does-discarding-message-for-event-0-because-of-too-many-unprocessed-m)
Yes, My locationManager run on main thread (it work pretty good in Debug mode and without it).

I also try in Simulator (it also stuck I think with some different reason but I need to test it mainly on device because my app Heavily depend on user location). 
 I set every possible configuration to debug in my scheme.
I tried to restart the device.
I tried on iphone 5s and 4.
(I use Xcode6 Ios8 ).

Does anyone had some similar problem or an idea what can I try?
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end I found the problem. Well the problem was pretty stupid I believe not many people will ever have this kind of issue but i will post my silly mistake.
While I developed the app I included a lot of logs there (some response from the server) as the time passed I forgot to remove them (of course before the release I would ).
That what actually stuck the app when it was running using tools.
That the response I received from apple support:

> As NSLog also writes on the main thread, it was blocking both the map display and the location manager.
>   One thing to keep in mind is, although NSLog is generally used for printing our debug information, that is not it’s real job.
>   If you look at the Foundation Framework Reference docs, NSLog is described as: Logs an error message to the Apple System Log facility.
>   Therefore it is a very heavyweight call, and effects the performance of apps a lot.

and indeed when I run  "Time profiler" I noticed that percentage time of running Nslog in some method are quite heigh.......